# Display Account Records from 2 PM To 2 PM

Tags: salesforce, report, admin

I need to build a report on Accounts where my criteria should contains
Records that are created from yesterdays 7 AM To todays 7 AM

[Please help me to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD96y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formula field on the record of type "Checkbox" containing the following:

```
AND(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) >= TODAY() -1,
    OR(
        AND(
            DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) = TODAY() -1,
            TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) >= TIMEVALUE("07:00:00.000")
        ),
        AND(
            DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) = TODAY(),
            TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate) <= TIMEVALUE("19:00:00.000")
        )
    )
)
```

(you might need to adjust the time values (07 and 19) to adjust for your time zone as formula's use GMT values)

Next filter your report on accounts that have this checkbox set to TRUE.

If it's child records you are looking for, you need to do a few extra steps, one of the options than is to create a report filter (or type) that only shows accounts that have at least one record with this checkbox set to TRUE.